# Disable Shortcut Menu Bar in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to disable the "Shortcut Menu Bar". Through `View->Appearance` I can disable the side bar, status bar, activity bar, editor area, panel and from `View` I can disable the breadcrumbs. I don't see an option for it. I call it "Shortcut Menu bar" as this is the only way I've seen it been mentioned (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerrygoyal.shortcut-menu-bar)

See the bar next to Landing.tsx:
[image: See the bar next to Landing.tsx]

Thanks!

Comment: IIUC this comes from the GitLens extension. Disable or uninstall that. Or check if it has customization [settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#) that fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, those do come from GitLens. You can install other packages that add items there too. I wasn't able to find the setting in GitLens so I was trying to find it in VSCode (since it allows you to even disable the editor area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the vscode settings json.

Press **Ctrl+Shift+P** on **Windows** (**Cmd+Shift+P** on **OSX**) and type "settings.json"
OR
`File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down to find "Edit in settings.json"`

2. Add the following setting

```
    "gitlens.menus": {
        "editorGroup": {
            "blame": false,
            "compare": false
        }
    }
```

3. Reload vscode. Either manually or press **Ctrl+Shift+P** on **Windows** (**Cmd+Shift+P** on **OSX**) and type "reload window"